# Sublevel entries of tree missing in view

Tags: python, qtreeview, pyside2

I try to read some hierarchical from a server and then display it accordingly in a QTreeView. I've managed to successfully transfer the received data into a QItemModel, but I've got some problems with the view. There is only the root item displayed and none of the children.

I receive the data as a nested list where something like [a,[b,c]] means, that b and c are children of a. I constructed an ItemModel that represents such relations. I set this model in a QTreeView to be displayed.

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
import threading
import sys


class TestItem(QtGui.QStandardItem):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._parent = parent
        self.name = data
        self.children = []
        if parent is not None:
            parent.append_child(self)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return id(self) == id(other)

    def append_child(self, item):
        self.children.append(item)

    def get_children(self):
        return self.children

    def get_child(self, row):
        return self.children[row]

    def get_children_count(self):
        return len(self.children)

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_parent(self):
        return self._parent

    def get_row(self):
        if self._parent:
            return self._parent.children.index(self)


class TestItemDataModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.test_items = []
        self.root_test_item = TestItem("root")

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole and index.isValid():
            test_item = index.internalPointer()
            name = test_item.get_name()
            return name
        else:
            return None

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        if not parent.isValid():
            parent_test_item = self.root_test_item
        else:
            parent_test_item = parent.internalPointer()
        return parent_test_item.get_children_count()

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return 1

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return "TestItems"

    def parent(self, index):
        test_item = index.internalPointer()
        parent = test_item.get_parent()

        if parent == self.root_test_item:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
        else:
            return self.createIndex(parent.get_row(), 0, parent)

    def index(self, row, column, parent):
        if not parent.isValid():
            parent_test_item = self.root_test_item
        else:
            parent_test_item = parent.internalPointer()

        child = parent_test_item.get_child(row)

        if child:
            return self.createIndex(row, column, child)
        else:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def flags(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.Qt.NoItemFlags
        else:
            return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled

    def insert_item(self, name, parent=None):
        test_item = self.make_item_entry(name, parent)
        self.appendRow(test_item)
        self.dataChanged.emit(QtCore.QModelIndex(), QtCore.QModelIndex(), [])

    def make_item_entry(self, item, parent=None, iterated_depth=0):
        if iterated_depth == 0:
            self.test_items = item
        if parent is None:
            parent = self.root_test_item
        if isinstance(item, str):
            return TestItem(item, parent)
        parent_snapshot = TestItem(item[0], parent)
        for i in range(0, len(item)):
            if isinstance(item[i], str):
                if i < len(item) - 1:
                    if isinstance(item[i+1], list):
                        self.make_item_entry(item[i+1], parent_snapshot, iterated_depth+1)
                    elif i != 0:
                        TestItem(item[i], parent)
                else:
                    TestItem(item[i], parent)
        return parent_snapshot

    def get_test_items(self):
        return self.test_items

    def reset_model(self):
        self.test_items = []
        self.clear()


class TestItemTreeView(QtWidgets.QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setModel(TestItemDataModel())
        self.watch_items_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.watch_items)
        self.watch_items_thread.daemon = True

    def start_test(self):
        self.watch_items_thread.start()

    def watch_items(self):
        while True:
            self.check_for_updates()

    def check_for_updates(self):
        old_data = self.model().get_test_items().copy()
        new_data = ['abc', ['foo', 'bar']].copy()
        found_new = self.check_for_new_items(old_data, new_data)
        not_found_old = self.check_for_deleted_items(old_data, new_data)
        if found_new or not_found_old:
            self.model().reset_model()
            self.update_data_model()

    def check_for_new_items(self, old_data, new_data):
        for i in range(0, len(new_data)):
            found = False
            for j in range(0, len(old_data)):
                if isinstance(new_data[i], str) and isinstance(old_data[j], str):
                    if new_data[i] == old_data[j]:
                        found = True
                elif isinstance(new_data[i], list) and isinstance(old_data[j], list):
                    if new_data[i][0] == old_data[j][0]:
                        found = not self.check_for_new_items(old_data[j][1], new_data[i][1])
            if not found:
                return True
        return False

    def check_for_deleted_items(self, old_data, new_data):
        for i in range(0, len(old_data)):
            found = False
            for j in range(0, len(new_data)):
                if isinstance(new_data[j], str) and isinstance(old_data[i], str):
                    if old_data[i] == new_data[j]:
                        found = True
                elif isinstance(new_data[j], list) and isinstance(old_data[i], list):
                    if new_data[j][0] == old_data[i][0]:
                        found = not self.check_for_deleted_items(old_data[i][1], new_data[j][1])
            if not found:
                return True
        return False

    def update_data_model(self):
        test_items = ['abc', ['foo', 'bar']]
        self.model().insert_item(test_items)
        self.expandAll()


class VMGui(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.screen = app.primaryScreen()
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.tree_view = TestItemTreeView()
        self.test_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Test")
        self.test_button.clicked.connect(self.tree_view.start_test)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tree_view, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.test_button, 0, 1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = VMGui()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is a reduced example of my code. I tried to make it as minimalistic as possible.
Instead of actually connecting to the server here I feed a hardcoded list into the program that matches the format. By clicking the test button this list is read and and TestItem is constructed containing the hierarchical structure. Then this constructed item is appended to the to the DataModel which is set in the TreeView.

I'd expect to see a fully expanded tree after clicking the Test button like:

```
-abc
---foo
---bar
```

What is actually displayed is only:

```
-abc
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the meaning of *iterated_depth*?

Comment: In this context it has no meaning. In the actual program I check the server for updates regularly. I store a local copy of the data I retrieve by the server. `iterated_depth` ensures that I do not overwrite this local copy by subsets of the data.

Comment: I have another question, I think that the data structure you use is not correct, for example in your code you use `['abc', ['foo', 'bar']]`, for the next image what is the structure: https://i.imgur.com/rX2D6wk.png?

Comment: `[A, [B,C], D, [E, F], G]` would be the structure. As I said, that is not 'my' data structure, it is, what I get from the server. There might be some flaws in my handling, but that's not the problem I'm looking at right now.

Comment: okay, from what I understand is that the children of the item are going to be a list on the right side: `..., x, [child_of_xs], ...`. Finally in my possible solution I will not use iterated_depth since I do not understand its meaning but I think you can add it, okay?

Comment: Yeah, that's okay. I wouldn't even expect a completely working example. I just need someone to point me in the right direction, since I absolutely have no clue, what I've done wrong.

Comment: In your case I do not think analyze where the problem is since that involves a lot of time.It is time that I will forget most of your code and I will do it from scratch so I have the *bad habit* of providing a MWE :-)